# Context-free grammar how to have same number of variables within a language

Tags: context-free

I am trying to get a CFG for the language:

> The set $A$ of odd-length strings in $\{a,b\}^*$ whose first, middle and last symbols are all the same.

(some example of correct answers would be: a, aaa, ababa, aababba, some incorrect answers include: ɛ, aaaa, abbaa)

This is what I've done so far:

```
S = a|b|aTaTa|bTbTb
T = aT|bT|ɛ
```

However the problem is, I need T to be a string of any combination of 'a's and 'b's but of the same length, but I'm not sure how to express this. As you can see above, I can get strings made up of any combination, but they won't be the same length when passed to S.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach won't work. Whenever you try to match the length of two non-terminals, that should be a big red flag your approach won't work.

Here's a hint: expand from the middle out, after starting with $S = a \mid b \mid aAa \mid bBb$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I have realized the correct way to do it now :) Will post my solution in a sec, once I fine-tune the logic.

Comment: `S = a | b | aAa | bBb, A = aAa | aAb | bAa | bAb | a, B = aBa | aBb | bBa | bBb | b`

Comment: @DoubleRainbowZ Correct.